# WordPress perform same search on all pages

Tags: wordpress, search

I have native WordPress search functionality in a menu which appears on each page. It is implemented by `searchform.php`.

```
// searchform.php
<form class="form">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search" value="<?php the_search_query('any'); ?>" required/>
        <button type="submit" class="search-button"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I run a search on the homepage (`example.com/`) the search runs correctly and pulls the correct template, `search.php`. The url which the search returns on is `example.com/?post_type=any&s=chocolate`.

However, if I go to another page (`example.com/services`, for example) and use the same search feature, the search results are different and it tries to pull from another template. The url which the search returns on is `example.com/services/?s=chocolate`.

Why does the search behave differently on pages other than the home page? How do I get the search to perform the same across all pages / posts like it does on the homepage (that is, resolve to the url `example.com/?post_type=any&s=chocolate`)? The search should query all pages and post types.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my `form` tag I added the following attribute  `action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"` and the search functionality is working throughout the site as desired.